# Why does the H2 database file grow much bigger than data size?

Tags: java, database, h2, filesize

I had H2 database of approximately 500MB.

The version of H2 is 1.2.147.

The storage engine of the database is PageStore.

The JDBC URLs are as follows.

> jdbc:h2:file://C:/H2/client;IFEXISTS=TRUE;MVCC=TRUE;DATABASE_EVENT_LISTENER='dummy.H2DBMonitor';AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;LOG=2

I made a version of H2 1.4.192 without changing the storage engine of the database.

When my customer used a database, the problem that the file size of the database expanded to up to 80GB occurred.

The database file should become small when I close a connection, but the size of my database file does not become small and may grow big.

It is a phenomenon not to occur in 1.2.147.

Is this problem a bug of the H2 database?

In addition, I get the following errors from trace.db.

> pageStore: Transaction log could not be truncated; size: 462MB

Is the error related to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with 5.2GB database file. I executed the following command in the H2 Console:

```
shutdown compact
```

and now i have a 300MB file. Maybe it can help you.

For more detailed steps:
https://stambia.org/kb/17-runtime-issues/147-the-h2-log-database-s-file-won-t-reduce-after-a-session-purge

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I add the following statement to the jdbc url.

```
DEFRAG_ALWAYS=TRUE
```

2 GB file becomes 300MB. It is defragmented when the db is closed.